# oracle execute immediate command concatenation

Tags: oracle, plsql

oracle execute immediate command concatenation. e.g.

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE Foo'; END;
```

works.

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''DROP TABLE ' || tableName || ''''; END;
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''DROP TABLE ' || 'Foo'''; END;
```

not working.

Table name is an input parameter in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your single quotes are improper.

Use following:

```
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || tableName; END;
BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || 'Foo'; END;
```

Cheers!!